# Как структурировать базу данных для школы танцев?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Делаю web-приложение для школы танцев. Приложение должно отображать список групп, список студентов в этих группах, время проведения тренировки. Естественно добавление и удаление. Для начала нужна база данных, в которой будут храниться и откуда будут брать данные.

Я набросал:

[image: Diagram Database]

Подскажите что исправить или добавить)

Comment: у студентов лишнее `id_group`, для осуществления связи многие-ко-многим можно добавить таблицу `student_group` c полями `id, student_id, group_id`. первичный ключ таблиц лучше просто называть `id`. По имени таблицы и так ясно, чей это идентификатор. Ну и count_student вряд-ли стоит хранить. Количество студентов в группе можно посчитать потом, в запросах.

Comment: Не соглашусь по поводу имени первичного ключа, что он должен быть просто `id`. есть куча рекомендаций, которые говорят о том, что в таблицах ключи должны иметь одно и тоже имя с постфиксом (например, `id_student`). По поводу структуры: в жизни цена зависит, как от мастерства тренера, так и от танца, времени занятия. Может  стоит перенести `Price` в таблицу `student_group`.